# Code from a tutorial on CMS. Index page only calls the constructor. What is going on with $this->connection->query($query);?

Tags: php

Here is the code:

```
if(!class_exists('DB')) {
    class DB {

        public function __construct() { 
            $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','','cms');

            if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
                printf("Connect failed %s\n",$mysqli->connect_error);
                exit();
            }

            $this->connection = $mysqli;
        }

        public function insert() {
            $query = "INSERT INTO post_title
                    VALUES ('title')";
            $result = $this->connection->query($query);
            return $result;
        }
    }
}

?>
```

I just dont understand how two -> is being used in $this->connection->query($query);. Also dont understand query($query). Is both query and $query the same? I'm just over all lost with this code any input much appreciated

Comment: the `->query() ` is a function of the object `$this->connection` it is a Mysqli object , the `$query` is a string variable that is declared inside the `insert()` function

Comment: Is this the full code of the class? `$this->connection` refers to a class variable with name `connection` but I don't see it in code (and the class is not derived from any parent class using `extends`. `query()` is a function while `$query` is a string variable filled with the statement to execute. As you don't know these basic mechanics you should read a basic tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it now.  query is a built in method i believe.  $this->connection is used to grab the object $mysqli from the constructor method, to then call the query method which takes in a query parameter hence the reason $query was passed in.  I could be completely wrong or somewhat wrong, any input or further explanation I may not realize greatly appriciated.

Comment: as far as this being all of the class i dont freaking know its from a tutorial